# OnChangeText event priority

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to make very basic android dictionary app. When letters are entered into textinput, app will search words from database and list corresponding words.But, The app gives an alert when I enter letters in order of 1,2,3,4 ==>  empty, "1", "12", "123".  These are the alerts what I expect "1", "12", "123", "1234".  How to fix this problem?

```
 const [searchtext, setSearchText] = useState("");
<TextInput
      style={{ marginHorizontal: 8 }}
      onChangeText={
        (text) => setSearchText(text)+ SearchWords(text)
      }
      placeholder="Search Word"
      value={searchtext}
       />

const SearchWords = () => { alert(searchtext);
db.transaction(txn => {
  txn.executeSql(
    'SELECT * FROM words where english like (?)',
    [`${searchtext}%`],
    (sqlTxn, res) => {
      console.log("words retrieved successfully");
      let len = res.rows.length;
      if (len > 0) {
        let results = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          let item = res.rows.item(i);
          results.push({ id: item.id, english: item.english, turkish: item.turkish });
        }
        setWords(results);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error on getting words" + error.message);
    },
  );
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. Solution is:

```
<TextInput
  style={{ marginHorizontal: 8 }}
  onChangeText={
    (text) => SearchWords(text)
  }
  placeholder="Search Word"
   />


const SearchWords = () => { 
db.transaction(txn => {
 txn.executeSql(
'SELECT * FROM words where english like (?)',
[`${text}%`],
(sqlTxn, res) => {
  console.log("words retrieved successfully");
  let len = res.rows.length;
  if (len > 0) {
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      let item = res.rows.item(i);
      results.push({ id: item.id, english: item.english, turkish: item.turkish });
    }
    setWords(results);
  }
},
error => {
  console.log("error on getting words" + error.message);
},
 );
     });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).